# Correct regex to block POST request and GET request to single file in apache?

Tags: regex, fail2ban

What's the correct fail2ban regex to block these kind of requests?

The excerpt is from apache access.log

```
181.204.83.115 - - [28/Mar/2024:17:38:47 +0200] "POST /login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 11593
```

and

```
181.204.83.115 - - [28/Mar/2024:17:38:47 +0200] "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 11593
```

I tried those with no luck:

```
failregex   = ^<host> .* "POST /login.php
failregex  = ^<HOST> .* "GET /login.php
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*login.php*
failregex = [[]client <HOST>[]] - - "login.php"
failregex = ^ .* "POST .*login.php HTTP/.*" 200
```

But I get when running fail2ban-regex:

```
No 'host' group in '/etc/filter.d/filternamefile.conf'
Cannot remove regular expression. Index 0 is not valid
```